# Algorithm for allocating percentage

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, algorithm, charts

Let's say I have this object.

```
 const data = {
      bills: 10,
      rent: 40,
      food: 50,
    }
```

They equal a 100 (or 100%).

Now let's say I assign `bills` a value of 20. This should make the other properties update like so

```
{
 bills: 20,
 rent: 30,
 food: 50,
}
```

or

```
 {
   bills: 20,
   rent: 35,
   food: 45,
 }
```

it doesn't matter.

I have this piece of code that I wrote, but sometimes, when I assign a property a value, one of the properties dips below, because the sum is 102, so one of the values is -2. as in this photo:
[image]

The piece of code is:

```
 allocatePercentage(dataName, percentage) {
    const curr = this.data[dataName];
    this.data[dataName] = percentage;
    if (percentage === 100) {
      Object.keys(this.data).filter(key => key !== dataName).forEach(dataKey => {
        this.data[dataKey] = 0;
      });
    } else {
      const {[dataName]: current, ...rest} = this.data;
      Object.keys(rest).forEach(key => {
        this.data[key] = this.data[key] - ((percentage - curr) / Object.keys(rest).length);
      });
    }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
allocatePercentage('bills', 20);
```

Let's assume that the object is this:

```
{
  bills: 10,
  rent: 40,
  food: 50,
}
```

for rent:

```
data['rent'] = 40 - ((20 - 10) / 2) // 35
```

for food:

```
data['food'] = 50 - ((20 - 10) / 2) // 45
```

Then why would it sometimes produce a negative % value? (like in the photo)

How do I prevent this behaviour and correctly allocate the percentage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't your answer be 20/36/44? You would get the difference of 100 and the old value and use that as your multiplier. I see a lot of ES6 spead magic happening, but sometimes it is better to understand it in a more traditional sense.

```json
{
  "bills": 20,
  "rent": 36,
  "food": 44
}
```

The `reallocate` function (seen below) should be called via:

```js
reallocate(data, 'bills', 20); // Modifies in-place and returns result
```

I set up an adhoc `testFn` function that handles calling the function with arguments and displays the result in the console along with a conditional to check the total percentage.

```js
const DEBUG = true;
const valuesEqual = (obj, expected) => Object.values(obj)
  .reduce((acc, v) => acc + v, 0) === expected;
const testFn = (fn, ...args) =>
  (res => console.log(JSON.stringify(res), '//', valuesEqual(res, 100)))
  (fn(...args));

const data = { bills: 10, rent: 40, food: 50 };

const reallocate = (categories, category, value) => {
  const oldVal     = categories[category] || 0,
        newValue   = categories[category] = value,
        other      = 100 - oldVal,
        diff       = newValue - oldVal,
        multiplier = (other - diff) / other;
  for (const cat in categories) {
    if (cat !== category) {
      categories[cat] = Math.round(categories[cat] * multiplier);
    }
  }
  return categories;
}

testFn(reallocate, { ...data }, 'bills', 20);         // Update - increment
testFn(reallocate, { ...data }, 'bills', 5);          // Update - decrement
testFn(reallocate, { ...data }, 'entertainment', 10); // Create
testFn(reallocate, { ...data }, 'bills', 0);          // Update - min
testFn(reallocate, { ...data }, 'bills', 100);        // Update - max
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Huh. I guess I got lost somewhere while writing this. This works! Thanks.

Comment: @filipbarak I improved it by removing DEBUG logic from the function. I wrote an adhoc test function.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it  like this:

```
Bills = 90
Rent = 10
Food = 0

if bills now is 100,
Bills = 100
Rent = 10-(100-90)/2 = 5
Food = 0 - (100-90)/2 = -5
```

So the calculation can not take equal portions out. You need to handle the case when any category goes or is 0.

Comment: That makes sense. How would one go about correcting this behavior, with the number of object properties being dynamic? (bills, food, rent, taxes,... n)

Comment: Well, that'll depend on how you want to split it b/w different categories. Since, the allocation won't be equally divided (with the possibility of one or more going to 0) then, the question is which categories you'll be okay to take more out off. It can be based on current percentage allocation.